# Binding to an ancestor treenode's datacontext property

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have TreeView structure defined as below:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootCollection}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

as you can see root elements have `green` foreground and all childrens are `black`
Now I want to change the foreground color of childrens from `black` to `red` on those childnodes whose parents have "`Failed`" property set to true.

For example if `RootCollection[0].Failed = true` then all `RootCollection[0].ChildNodes` on treeview should become `red` (rootnode stays `green`, and there wouldn't be any grandchildnodes in this case so it doesn't matter what will happen to them).

I tried setting DataTrigger Styles wherever I could and tried binding to `RelativeSource` in many different ways but I couldn't handle it.

Any help will be appreciated :)

---

DataContext is something like this:

```
public class MyTreeNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string text;
private ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode> childNodes;
private bool failed;

public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.text;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.text = value;
        Changed("Text");
    }
}

public bool Failed
{
    get
    {
        return this.failed;
    }
    set
    {
        this.failed = value;
        Changed("Text");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode> ChildNodes
{
    get
    {
        return this.childNodes;
    }
    set
    {
        this.childNodes = value;
        Changed("ChildNodes");
    }
}

private void string Changed(string propertyName)
{
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode> RootCollection { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
    this.RootCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode>
    {
        new MyTreeNode
        {
            Text = "first",
            Failed = true,
            ChildNodes = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode>
            {
                new MyTreeNode { Text = "first first" },
                new MyTreeNode { Text = "first second" }
            }
        },
        new MyTreeNode
        {
            Text = "second",
            ChildNodes = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode>
            {
                new MyTreeNode { Text = "second first" }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

it's simplified because my real code uses many custom classes.

Here's view structure from `Snoop`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnUJE.png

(I need to set property marked in blue based on property marked in red)

Comment: could you  post your datacontext code

Comment: you mean `RootCollection`? It's just an `ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode>`. `MyTreeNode` is just a simple class with properties `string Text`, `bool Failed` and `ObservableCollection<MyTreeNode> ChildNodes`

Comment: ok we need  it pease post it

Answer (score 0):

I can't check if this works at the moment, so it might not, but it looks about right. Try this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Failed, RelativeSource={
RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=1}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger> 
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

If it doesn't work, you could experiment a little with the `AncestorLevel` property, setting it to 2 or 3, or even removing it. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: hmmm, it doesn't work :( I've already tried this before but without setting "AncestorLevel". However - I tried setting it up to level 8 but it simply doesn't do anything

Comment: Maybe this http://i.imgur.com/XMF6rLN.png will help you helping me help us all? ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use template selector instead

//you put this in  your App.xaml

```
  <Application.Resources>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="failed" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
        <TextBlock Name="pTxt" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Text}" >
        </TextBlock>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="succeded" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
        <TextBlock Name="pTxt" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Text}" >
        </TextBlock>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

// and  here  in  your Window.cs

```
 public class ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
 {
     public override DataTemplate
         SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
         FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is MyTreeNode)
        {
            MyTreeNode treeNode = item as MyTreeNode;
            DataTemplate temp = null;
            if (treeNode.Failed)
                temp = App.Current.Resources["failed"] as HierarchicalDataTemplate;                
            else
                temp = App.Current.Resources["succeded"] as HierarchicalDataTemplate;

            return temp;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

// and this  in you  window.xaml.cs

```
 <TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding RootCollection}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <myApp:ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector></myApp:ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>



    </TreeView>
```

I tried it and it's work  perfectly
Hope this  help

Comment: Adassko let us know if this  can answer your question

Comment: Thank you, but the `Failed` changes dynamically during runtime and I don't think this approach will update the datatemplate

Comment: have you  got a solution  for this Adasko